# Mail-notification plugin Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04 not playing sound

Tags: sound, ubuntu-gnome, notification, evolution, mail-notification

I'm using Evolution mail that doesn't have background process constantly checking mail server to notify me on new mail income. It has plugin notifier that is active only when Evolution is running. I installed `sudo apt-get install mail-notification` and manually (looked Evolution outlook.com server settings) configured outlook imap server (evolution, gmail, yahoo, outlook... built in configuration doesn't work).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HgZ8.png)

So I basically check mail server independent of Evolution. I get notification as balloon in Gnome 3 notification area but sound doesn't play, not even when I click play sound. I copied that new-mail.wav file from mail-notification data folder /usr/share/mail-notification/new-mail.wav to Documents folder and conigured **Evolution mail-notification pluging** using dconf to play sound file instead beep

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3hzH.png)

and Evolution mail accepted that, but that has nothing to do with that mail-notification pluging that gives balloon in system notification area. It has option `play file` and can't play nothing, neither I can configure it in dconf (can't find that program). I could probably configure system notification to play some sound every time I get notificaton, but I need to trigger sound only for that program. What can I do?

EDIT

Downloaded program from here www.nongnu.org/mailnotify can't post links need more rep

```
jake@jake-Aspire-V3-771:~/Downloads/mail-notification-5.4$ ./jb configure
building jb...
jbsrc/lib/src/core/jb-main.c: In function ‘jb_main’:
jbsrc/lib/src/core/jb-main.c:164:3: error: ‘g_type_init’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
   g_type_init();
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:23,
                 from jbsrc/lib/src/core/jb-variable.h:26,
                 from jbsrc/lib/src/core/jb-main.c:25:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:681:23: note: declared here
 void                  g_type_init                    (void);
                       ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
jbsrc/lib/src/core/jb-util.c: In function ‘print_warning_or_error’:
jbsrc/lib/src/core/jb-util.c:225:3: error: function might be possible candidate for ‘gnu_printf’ format attribute [-Werror=suggest-attribute=format]
   message = g_strdup_vprintf(format, args);
   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
ERROR: cannot build jb
```

I will tray out to change compile options, warning ok

**EDIT**

No need to compile from source, this fixed my sound problems

```
gconftool --set /apps/mail-notification/sounds/play-command --type string \
          "exec gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=%file ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! pulsesink >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences audible-bell` ?

Comment: don't know i remove that package apt-get remove mail-notification and trying manual installation, check edit

Comment: sorry been busy, edit my post later,  this is  program http://www.nongnu.org/mailnotify/ but I get stupid errors compiling, threat warrning as error /usr/include/glib-2.0/ error: ‘g_type_init’ is deprecated,  i got latest glib headers...